# How can I set a .jpg as window background in python ursina?

Tags: python, background, ursina

How can I an image as the background in my ursina project. I know I can change the color of the background by using `window.color = color.light_gray` for example. But how do I use an image?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Sky(texture="texture_name")
```